# Running integration/e2e tests on top of a Kubernetes stack

Tags: software-testing, cloud

I’ve been digging a bit into the way people run integration and e2e tests in the context of Kubernetes and have been quite disappointed by the lack of documentation and feedbacks. I know there are amazing tools such as kind or minikube that allow to run resources locally. But in the context of a CI, and with a bunch of services, it does not seem to be a good fit, for obvious resources reasons. I think there are great opportunities with running tests for:

- Validating manifests or helm charts
- Validating the well behaving of a component as part of a bigger whole
- Validating the global behaviour of a product

The point here is not really about the testing framework but more about the environment on top of which the tests could be run.

Do you know any tools that could allow to spin up a cluster in seconds, on top of which I could run the tests and then get rid of it ? Or maybe another approach for achieving similar things.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Izzy I rephrased my question :) Let me know if it still doesn't fit.

Comment: Well, vaguely. Not really my area of expertise, so I won't argue :)